# Google Analytics – why events are not registered in goals?

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I wanted to track end registration conversions for Source/Medium in Google Analytics. I've created an event goal for that:

[1. Goal screenshot from GA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHhkh.png)

In order to fire the appropriate event that should be passed to goal, I use this code on a separate Double opt-in registration page, where user gets only once per life-time.

```
ga('send', {
      hitType: 'event',
      eventCategory: 'registration',
      eventAction: 'test'
    });
```

This event flows into goal, but very poorly, more than half of the events are not registered. If we compare exact same day to Facebook Pixel (which also fires in the same place), then this GA Goal shows 40-60% less conversions on average than FB pixel.

We've then additionally added

```
ga('set', 'transport', 'beacon');
```

And also added a forced timed hitCallback, so that it would definitely be sent.

We've also added a second test Goal and event for it, to measure end goal reach day to day.

[2. Second, test goal screenshot from GA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmq2e.png)

This new event is fired in the same place, so it should be written in appropriate goal as well. But it's not. It's been more than 48 hours and goal is still empty.

[3. Test goal is empty, but it should have around 95+ registered events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnNux.png)

Events from both goals are recorded correctly and are shown in appropriate screenshots:

[4. Test goal – events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tayVY.png)

[5. Initial goal – doi events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4GMy.png)

Can anyone please help me to understand why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I can suggest:

**Non-reporting of Test goal**

The `Category` setting is case-sensitive and needs to match exactly what is reported by the event.

- Your event hit sends a hit with category `registration`
- Yet your goal setting is looking for a `Category` that equals `Register`

Recommendation: change `Category equals to Register` to `Category equals to registration`

**Mismatch of goals to total events**

I can't tell exact numbers of event hits vs goal completions from your screenshots. However, even without this information, the key reason why the numbers won't match is: Goals report on how many **sessions** resulted in a conversion. So if a user triggers a goal event multiple times in a session, it will simply be counted as 1 conversion